# Django // Daphne 500 error on all requests after version update "TypeError: object HttpResponse can't be used in 'await' expression"

Tags: django, azure, django-channels, open-telemetry, asgi

I have a problem where I'm getting 500 responses after updating Django from version 3.1.13 to 3.2.8.

The issue wasn't occurring on the previous version of Django, and it only occurs if **both** the Django Channels app and OpenCensus middleware are enabled in `settings.py`.

I would really appreciate if someone can help verify that my `asgi.py` and `settings.py` are configured correctly, or identify the dependency causing the issue so that I can follow through and raise a bug.

##### Repo that reproduces the issue

https://github.com/oscarhermoso/bug-opentelemetry-django-asgi

##### Daphne error as it appears in the browser

> ### 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Exception inside application.
> *Daphne*

##### ASGI entrypoint

```py
# testproject/asgi.py

import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

# os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'testproject.settings')

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack  # noqa
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter  # noqa

import testproject.routing  # noqa

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
    "http": get_asgi_application(),

    # WebSocket chat handler
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            testproject.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

##### Installed apps and middleware

```py
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'opencensus.ext.django.middleware.OpencensusMiddleware'
]
```

##### Error Dump

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 09, 2021 - 10:59:03
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'testproject.with_both'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.4 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception inside application: object HttpResponse can't be used in 'await' expression
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/asgi.py", line 161, in __call__
    response = await self.get_response_async(request)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 150, in get_response_async
    response = await self._middleware_chain(request)
TypeError: object HttpResponse can't be used in 'await' expression
HTTP GET / 500 [0.97, 127.0.0.1:41256]

Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception inside application: object HttpResponse can't be used in 'await' expression
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/asgi.py", line 161, in __call__
    response = await self.get_response_async(request)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 150, in get_response_async
    response = await self._middleware_chain(request)
TypeError: object HttpResponse can't be used in 'await' expression
HTTP GET /favicon.ico 500 [0.90, 127.0.0.1:41256]
```

Comment: Removing `opencensus` stops the issue from happening?

Comment: Correct @IainShelvington. I'm using the library for traces in Azure and need to keep the package installed

Comment: As you have already opened an issue on GitHub, Posting the link here to help other community members: [ASGI Django with OpencensusMiddleware erroring on all requests with TypeError: object HttpResponse can't be used in 'await' expression](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/issues/1082)

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço - No workaround yet, I'm continuing to use Django 3.1 until I get some feedback on the linked GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still looking for a solution.
But, after some research, I've found that there is an issue with the  get_asgi_application.

I've read that the HTTP protocol is added by default by Django and for that reason, we don't need this line. After I delete `"http": get_asgi_application(),` the website started to work well.

There is a person talking about this here: https://djangokatya.wordpress.com/2020/10/26/500-internal-server-error-daphne-http-processing-error/

Anyway, on Channels' V3 documentation they ask explicitly to add `"http": get_asgi_application(),`... Don't know how it works without it, but it does for me.

The issue is: after this, I started to get an error in Daphne: `ValueError: HTTP response has not yet been started but got http.response.body`. Can't understand well what is happening up to now.

Comment: Your error seems directly related to ASGI/WSGI configuration - 

`HTTP response has not yet been started but got http.response.body` check out the response on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/344